# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found when configuring JBoss EAP 7.1 Client

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to configure my ESB server as a client for JBoss EAP 7.1 integrated Active MQ Artemis which will connect using the RemoteConnectionFactory. However, I couldn't use the JBoss client jar as it conflicts with the internal JARs. Therefore, I added all the necessary JARs separately.

Now an exception is being thrown saying no provider found.

I have added both xnio-api and xnio-nio jars.

Below is the exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found
    at org.xnio.Xnio.doGetInstance(Xnio.java:226)
    at org.xnio.Xnio.getInstance(Xnio.java:192)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.EndpointCache.get(EndpointCache.java:47)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.createEndpoint(InitialContextFactory.java:226)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateEndpoint(InitialContextFactory.java:207)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:170)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:146)
    ... 50 more
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: This problem isn't directly related to ActiveMQ Artemis. This is a JNDI problem. The two things are 100% independent.

Comment: Have you checked the `/bin/client/README-EJB-JMS.txt` file in the JBoss EAP installation directory? It describes the content of the `jboss-client.jar`, which is much more than `xnio-api` and `xnio-nio`. In particular I think you're missing the netty jar which provides the XNIO implementation

Comment: You could also add the xnio-nio-3.0.x.GA-redhat-1.jar (whichever is shipped with your eap) in the application's classpath ,or ad this jar as dependency in your pom.xml if using maven